# Android app to convert handwritten math equations to LaTeX code

Tags: android, latex, math, ocr

I found some programs to convert handwritten math equations into latex code such as:

- MyScript Mathpad (only iOS)
- [InLage](http://www.inlage.com/) (only Windows)

But I didn't find any app for android. Is there any app for android with that feature? It doesn't need to be free.

Comment: There is an online demo from myscript [link](http://webdemo.myscript.com/#/demo/equation). Maybe, they will release an android app some day :)

Comment: I've build a website for single symbol recognition [write-math.com](http://write-math.com). Does it have to be an app? Why? - Oh, by the way, MyScript does not do OCR. They do on-line recognition, not off-line recognition. That means they use the information how the symbol is written. You can't feed an image into their system.

Answer (score 1):

[MyScript](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myscript.smartnote) is an Android application that lets you write your notes as well as math formulas. It recognizes math objects and can export to LaTeX

Edit: this seems to have deprecated and it no longer available for download.

Comment: I get "Sorry! This content is not available in your country yet" from Canada? Is that really a thing?

Comment: Seems like they removed the application. I see the same error. Probably just hasn't been updated in years.

Answer (score 1):

## [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/)

> The Mathpix desktop app allows users to take screenshots of math equations and paste the extracted Latex, all with a single keyboard shortcut.
>
> It's an indispensable utility for anyone who works with Latex or wishes to do so.

The Android app is available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathpix.mathpixandroid&hl=en_US)

[image: MathPix app]

From the recognized expression the app can solve it, graph it or search for more information on Wolfram Alpha

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Mathematical Expression Recognition](http://cat.prhlt.upv.es/mer/)

> ### overview
>
> This is a *work-in-progress* demonstrator of a Mathematical Expression Recognizer (Last update: September, 2016).
>
> The recognition engine is based on [SESHAT](https://github.com/falvaro/seshat), an open-source system for recognizing handwritten math expressions.
>
> ### instructions
>
> 1. Write an expression on the 'draw here' area.
> 2. Click on the 'send' link to translate it to a LaTeX equation.

It's just a webpage so it can work on any platforms